# How to export arguments for terra's app function when using multiple cores?

Tags: raster, r, terra

Suppose the following example:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast()
r1 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))
r2 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))
r3 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))

rs <- c(r1,r2,r3)

custom_fun <- function(x, offset){
  mean(x) + offset
}

offset_memmory = 10

app(x = rs,
    fun = function(i) custom_fun(i, offset = offset_memmory))
```

I can use `app` successfully using `offset` argument. However, I can't use the same function while using multiple cores:

```
app(x = rs,
    fun = function(i) custom_fun(i, offset = offset_memmory),
    cores = 3)
# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
#   360 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "custom_fun"

app(x = rs,
    fun = function(i) ff(i, offset),
    cores = 3,
    ff = custom_fun)
# Error: [app] cannot use this function
# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...): unused argument (ff = function (x, offset) 
# {
#     mean(x) + offset
# })

app(x = rs,
    fun = function(i) ff(i, offset),
    cores = 3,
    ff = custom_fun,
    offset = offset_memmory)
# Error: [app] cannot use this function
# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...): unused argument (ff = function (x, offset) 
# {
#     mean(x) + offset
# }, offset = 10)
```

I'm looking for something similar than `args` from `raster::clusterR` function. What would be `terra`'s approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would run this sequentially

```
app(rs, custom_fun, offset=offset_memmory)
```

With version 1.5-43 (currently the development version, you can install it with  `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`) you can now do

```
app(rs, custom_fun, offset=offset_memmory, cores=2)
```

With earlier versions (and perhaps in some other cases), you can pass a cluster object that has the objects you need, like this:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl, "offset_memmory")
app(rs, custom_fun, offset=offset_memmory, cores=cl)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Amazing, I compared a complex function (dtw classification with asymmetrical step over 22 patterns for a SpatRaster of 300 x 300 x 47) and this method takes 663 sec. While using mclapply (transforming raster to df, then splitting, and converting back to raster) takes 769 secs. Both with 8 cores in macOS. I will test it in Windows with 12 cores, since I can't use mclappy in that OS

Comment: Dear, Robert. The approach described for terra 1.5-43 worked in macOS. The same approach with the same library version didn't work in Windows, but the second approach worked well. Just a heads-up

Comment: It works fine for me on windows.